# C#: Set "Sign in as" for Windows Service directly in ProjectInstaller

Tags: c#, windows-services, windows-installer

I have created a **Windows Service** for a WCF-RESTful application. On the server where I run the service, I need to sign in as a user from the domain to access the database within the service. That means that when I want to update the **Windows Service** (deinstallation & new installation), every time I need to set this user manually in the properties of the service again.

In C# I configured the following to create the **Windows Service**:

```
public class WindowsService : ServiceBase {
    public ServiceHost serviceHost = null;

    public WindowsService () {
        this.ServiceName = "Processing Engine Interface"
    }

    public static void Main () {
        Run(new WindowsService());
    }

    protected override void OnStart (string[] args) {
        this.serviceHost?.Close();

        this.serviceHost = new ServiceHost(new RestService());

        this.serviceHost.Open();
    }

    protected override void OnStop () {
        if (this.serviceHost == null) return;
        this.serviceHost.Close();
        this.serviceHost = null;
    }
}

[RunInstaller(true)]
public class ProjectInstaller : Installer {
    private ServiceProcessInstaller process;
    private ServiceInstaller service;

    public ProjectInstaller () {
        this.process = new ServiceProcessInstaller {Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem};
        this.service = new ServiceInstaller {
            ServiceName = "Processing Engine Interface"
        };
        this.Installers.Add(this.process);
        this.Installers.Add(this.service);
    }
}
```

My question is, if it is possible to already set the account (using username and password) in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ServiceProcessInstaller class has Account, UserName, and Password properties.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ddhy0byf(v=vs.110).aspx

If you are in fact using Windows Installer and a tool other than Visual Studio there is no need for code because the other tools (such as WiX) supply support for Windows Installer's built-in ServiceInstall and ServiceControl functionality.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I didn't find these properties at design time, just available at code. I think this link is a more especific reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.serviceprocessinstaller.account?view=netframework-4.7.1